# How do I setup a proper 404 page?

Tags: 7

At present, my Drupal 7 website’s "Page not found" is 301 redirected to a custom 404 page.

However, I just checked the HTTP response code for a random URL and I noticed it 301 redirects to a custom "Page not found" page, but that page returns a 200 HTTP response code.

Shouldn't the page response header be 404?

If that's the case how do I fix the response code to 404 in Drupal 7?

Comment: Since there is a redirect, what you define "custom 404 page" cannot set a 404 HTTP code, since it is retrieved. The redirect changes the status, and the new page can just return 200 as code to tell the browser it was found.

Comment: Thanks kiamlaluno yes that's what happening to my drupal setup. How do I fix this then? This would be a mess for SEO purposes.. and indexing in google etc.

Comment: You need to check what is causing the redirect, which is the main issue. If Drupal doesn't find a linked page, it returns a 404 error, so what you are describing is not the default behavior.

Comment: So I should just remove the redirect right?

Comment: @sd100 yes. Remove the redirect and let Drupal handle the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a 301 redirect to your custom 404 page, just go to

Admin > Config > System > Site Information

```
/admin/config/system/site-information
```

Enter your new path into the 404 error page box, and click "Save configuration".

You might also want to try the CustomError module:
https://www.drupal.org/project/customerror

Comment: can confirm, this is what I'm doing as well. But within the node that it redirects to when a 404 occures, I have it do `<?php include DRUPAL_ROOT. '/widgets/includes/404.php'; ?>` and within that 404.php page, it goes through a huge list of old URLs (from when the site was a Joomla thing) and forwards them to the new URL if there's a match.

Comment: Assuming the OP set the redirect to the custom 404 page, this is how he should have done. From the question is not clear why the redirect is happening, though.

Answer (score 0):

The default response of the not-found request is 404. Even if you use a custom page for 404 requests. The path to the page needs to set at `admin/config/system/site-information` for the
**`Default 404 (not found) page`**. Check the network tab for verifying the status of `Type` `document`.

Comment: I checked the site information page and the proper 404 pages node address is there.. what else should I check there? Thanks

Comment: @sd100 Try checking for the status in the Network tab of the developer tools in your browser on a URL which does not exist, like `/page/asdflksdf`. The `Type` should be 404 for `Type` "document".

Comment: Ok so done, and I see a 301 first, and a 404 below that in the "Status" column.